# Why does std::num_put take the ios_base parameter by non-const reference?

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream, facet, const-correctness

I'm experimenting with the iostreams / locale numeric facet and I've hit something quite curious:

The "canonical example" of using the [std::num_put facet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put) to directly format a number goes like this:

```
std::string f(double value) {
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
    num_put<char> const& npf = use_facet<num_put<char> >(ss.getloc());
    npf.put(/*out=*/ss, /*format=*/ss, /*fill=*/' ', value);
    return ss.str();
}
```

The **first parameter** to [`put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) is the thing where the output is written to.

We can also have code like this and it works:

```
std::string g(double value) {
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
    typedef char* CharBufOutIt;
    num_put<char, CharBufOutIt> const& npf = use_facet<num_put<char, CharBufOutIt> >(ss.getloc());
    char big_enough_buf[100];
    npf.put(/*out=*/big_enough_buf, /*format=*/ss, /*fill=*/' ', value);
    return big_enough_buf;
}
```

The **second parameter** to `put()` is a stream object that determines the specific formatting to be applied. The second parameter is *not modified* at all. (Not in my implementation, and not according to what [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) [describe](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/num-put.html#idx1009) this parameter to be for.)

However, the signature of `put`looks like this:

> iter_type put( iter_type out, **std::ios_base&** str, char_type fill, long
>   double v ) const;

That is, it is taking the ios_base object by *non-const* reference, even though it wouild appear it should really take it by **const** reference.

Am I missing something? Is this just a (historical?) peculiarity in the C++ iostreams spec? Has this ever been discussed by the C++ std committee?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `getLoc` is with const, however in the implementation from vs2013 the function `width(0)` is called, and that one is non const

Comment: @Raxvan Can you show me where it is const?

Comment: @0x499602D2 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/getloc/

Comment: @Raxvan Strange. On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc) it doesn't have const.

Comment: @0x499602D2 :)), interesting find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Standard](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) (22.4.2.2.2) the implementation of `put` is at one point as such:

> Stage 3:
>
> If `str.width()` is nonzero and the number of `charT’s` in the sequence after stage 2 is less than `str.width()`, then enough fill characters are added to the sequence at the position indicated for padding to bring the length of the sequence to `str.width()`. `str.width(0)` is called.`

Also, `str.width(0)` calls `width` declared without `const` (see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/)):

```
streamsize ios_base::width (streamsize wide);
```